# monitor hdmi cable with usb-c and hdmi input

Tags: display, hdmi, usb-c

Do you know if a monitor hdmi cable exists that has two inputs from either usb-c and hdmi [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7v3.png).
I would like to be able to use my monitor with both my laptop and my desktop. Or do you know a better, cheap solution? Help is appreciated.

Edit: Would (hdmi) <- (hdmi,hdmi) plus (hdmi)<-(usb-c) work?

Comment: No monitor cable has 2 inputs to one output. What's wrong with a USB-C->HDMI connector then a single HDMI->HDMI cable you swap between computers? btw, as seems to be common, you've listed the cables the wrong way round.

Comment: Why not using a HDMI switch?

Comment: Thanks both of you, ive looked into HDMI switch, and it solves the problem I think. @Tetsujin as to why not like your suggestion, I would not like to have to switch cables everytime. As I am going to buy something anyways, I figured I could make it as optimal as it could be.